# return type of linq group by multiple column

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following code:

```
 var studentClassAttendancesGrouped =
                            classAttendanceByCriteria.OrderBy(x => x.Lecture.Id).GroupBy(x => new { x.Lecture, x.Teacher });
```

I am trying to return `studentClassAttendancesGrouped`from a method.But I can not determine the return type of the method.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

[This](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534501(v=vs.90).aspx) overload of the `GroupBy` will return `IEnumerable<IGrouping<TKey, TSource>>` as seen from the [source code](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,58da5c33e7fdf03d).

You just need to project your enumerable  with the [`Select()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.select%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) and of course you must call [`ToList()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb342261%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) at the end to execute the query and create a list:

```
var res = classAttendanceByCriteria.OrderBy(x => x.Lecture.Id)
                                   .GroupBy(x => new { x.Lecture, x.Teacher })
                                   .Select(x => new {x.Key.Lecture, x.Key.Teacher})
                                   .ToList();
```

But, the above code creates a list of the anonymous types. If you are going to return the above statement from the method, then you need to use or to create a custom object and return the list of this:

```
public class LectureTeacher
{
    public string Lecture { get; set; }
    public string Teacher { get; set; }
}

public List<LectureTeacher> GetDogsWithBreedNames()
{
    var res = classAttendanceByCriteria.OrderBy(x => x.Lecture.Id)
                                       .GroupBy(x => new { x.Lecture, x.Teacher })
                                       .Select(x => new LectureTeacher {Lecture  = x.Key.Lecture, Teacher  = x.Key.Teacher})
                                       .ToList();

    return res;
}
```

***By the way,*** `GroupBy` has several other overloads which you can specify **result selector** and it will return `IEnumerable` to you:

```
myList.OrderBy(x => x.Lecture.Id) 
      .GroupBy(x => new { x.Lecture, x.Teacher } //key selector
               key => new LectureTeacher // result selector
               {
                    Lecture  = key.Lecture, 
                    Teacher  = key.Teacher
               }) 
      .ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you to create a custom class and return it from your method:-

```
IEnumerable<CustomType> studentClassAttendancesGrouped =
       classAttendanceByCriteria.OrderBy(x => x.Lecture.Id)
       .GroupBy(x => new { x.Lecture, x.Teacher })
      .Select(x => new CustomType { Lecture = x.Key.Lecture, Teacher = x.Key.Teacher });
```

Where, `CustomType` will look something like this:-

```
public class CustomType 
{
   public string Lecture {get; set; }
   public string Teacher {get; set; }
}
```

You can add more columns as per your need and finally return `IEnumerable<CustomType>` from your method.

Thus, your method will look like:-

```
public IEnumerable<CustomType> MyMethod()
{
    return classAttendanceByCriteria.OrderBy(x => x.Lecture.Id)
       .GroupBy(x => new { x.Lecture, x.Teacher })
       .Select(x => new CustomType { Lecture = x.Key.Lecture, Teacher = x.Key.Teacher });
}
```